# JSP чтение кириллицы из properties

Tags: java, кодировка, jstl

Есть приложение на Tomcat нужно сделать интернационализацию. Использую JSTL fmt теги, данные хранятся в файлах properties. Английский текст отображается правильно, а вот кириллица выводит примерно такие символы **ÐÑÐ¾Ð´** в JSP прописано:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="controller.internationalization.i18n.lang" var="lang" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Вопрос как сделать правильное отображение текста.

**Update**: решил через native2ascii сменить на кодировку ISO-8859-1, файл стал выглядеть так `signing=\u00d0\u0092\u00d1\u0085\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4`
результат не изменился, кириллица отображается криво

Comment: вопрос исчерпан, поменял с помощью native2ascii кодировку на UTF-8 и всё встало на свои места

Answer (score 1):

Нативная кодировка только ISO-8859-1, если есть spring, то поставьте его перекодировщик в web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```